# Removing single quotes on a column name in snowflake

Tags: sql, select, replace, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have come across a problem in a snowflake,

Query:

```
select 'name' as Name from profile
```

which returns the output as:

```
Name
________
name

name

name

name
.........
```

What I actually need is

```
select name as Name from profile
```

which will return the correct output which I expect as

```
Name
______________
Ram

Kishore

Rohit............
```

How will I remove the single quote in the select statement for the column name? I know its simple to just remove the single quote from name but my problem is that the name is a variable passed in a function and it is a varchar

Comment: can you provide the function code where you're passing in the variable? it should be pretty easy to generate the query in a function without the single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

`'name'` is a string, thus a constant, and why it is on every line.

A column `name` would ether be referenced with no quotes, or via double quotes `"name"`. But thus implies there is a column called name.

By default in Snowflake all tokens are case in sensitive if not double quoted as they are case to upper case, where as the tokens in double quotes are not projected to upper case form (unless the option to ignore case of double quoted names is on). So if you are directly want the name column to be output as `Name` then you will need to use `name as "Name"` to avoid it becoming `NAME`

Comment: "By default in Snowflake all tokens are case in sensitive if not double quoted as they are case to upper case, where as the tokens in double quotes are not projected to upper case form (unless the option to ignore case of double quoted names is on)" is a very difficult to read sentence.

Comment: ok, `this` is really `THIS`, `tHiS` is also `THIS` `"ThIs"` is `ThIs` if you have not fiddled with an option. When you fiddle with an option `"THis"` becomes `THIS`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the IDENTIFIER function, which has examples at the bottom of the below page:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifier-literal.html

Your example will look like:

```
select identifier('name') as Name from profile;
```

Comment: This hasn't worked for me. Getting an error "invalid identifier"